# Kde network notification on start-up at center

Tags: network-manager, kde, notification

I have installed Kubuntu 13.10 and after i login it show me a kde network notification on top-center screen. How can i disable or adjust this inconvenience. Here is a screenshot:

[image: http://it.tinypic.com/r/2rwx5c6/5]

Comment: I have the same problem. Doing anything in the desktop makes it go away.

Answer (score -1):

Same here. **Logging out and back in makes the message appear where it should.** This problem seems to exist only a first login.